# How to click on </span> Tag ? (Webbrowser - Delphi)

Tags: delphi, browser, click, html

how can i click on a "< / span>" tag in a html page ?

like this :

```
<span id="_ID_">Hello There</span>
```

Is it possible ?
Thanks

Comment: Take your mouse and place it above the `span` element. Hold down your index finger on the left mouse button for a brief moment; then release the finger.

Comment: Seriously though, you need to add more information about the context you want to do this in.

Comment: Btw, why did you set Delphi tag?

Comment: lol Pekka . Thanks for response dude

Comment: @LatinSuD , akhavi this question is about click on a span tag in the delphi using webbrowser control . is it clear or need more description ? also the title of topic is : How to click on </span> Tag ? (*Webbrowser - Delphi*) . can't you see it ?

Comment: @Kermia: Clicking is simple, as Pekka explained. Reacting on the click is more difficult. Simulating a click is even more difficult. Please explain in your question what you are really after.

Comment: I did ! there is a html page and we want to using delphi to click on a Tab that is created with a span tag . the span tag have id but it have no onclick event and it works with ajax techniques . it is easy to click on a submit button in a html page but in this case i can not select the Tab (or same span tag) . :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following :

```
procedure TMainFrm.ClickBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
 Document : IHTMLDocument2;
 SPAN, Temp : IHTMLElement;
 ElementCount, I : Integer;
begin
 if WB.Document = nil then
  begin
   MessageBox(Handle, 'First Load a Page in TWebBrowser !!', '', MB_OK+MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
   Exit;
  end;

 if SIDEdit.Text = '' then
  begin
   MessageBox(Handle, 'Enter SPAN ID !', '', MB_OK+MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
   Exit;
  end;

 Document := WB.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
 ElementCount := Document.all.length;
 for I := 0 to ElementCount - 1 do
  begin
   Temp := Document.all.item(I, '') as IHTMLElement;
   if (Temp.tagName = 'SPAN') and (Temp.id = SIDEdit.Text) then
    begin
     SPAN := Temp;
     Break;
    end;
  end;
 if SPAN <> nil then
  SPAN.click
 else
  MessageBox(Handle, 'No SPAN Tag with ID Entered Found !', '', MB_OK+MB_ICONINFORMATION);
end;
```

Put this Components on the Form :

**TWebBrowser** , Name : "**WB**" , for browsing the page

**TEdit** , Name : "**SIDEdit**" , for giving the SPAN tag ID

**TBitBtn** , Name : "**ClickBtn**" , the Code above is the OnClick Event of "ClickBtn"

I Think that the Code is Simple and Variables are understandable , if necessary tell me to explain the Code ...

[There is an Example](http://rapidshare.com/files/418712935/Click_on_SPAN_Tag_in_TWebBrowser.rar) ...

Good Luck ... !

Comment: Thank you so much Mr Mehri :)

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to say "how can i call the click event on a span element ?".
For a span element :

```
<span id="myId" onclick="myOnclikFunction()">Hello There</span>
```

In JavaScript you can simulate a click (seems work only on IE !) :

```
document.getElementById("myId").click();
```

With jQuery you can call the click event (and call the myOnclikFunction() function) on an element like this :

```
$('#myId').trigger("click");
```

or

```
$('#myId').click();
```

For information : `id="_ID_"` is not a HTML valid code. An id can't start by "_". It must begin with a letter A-Z or a-z (see [HTML id Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp)).

Comment: hi , tnx . and if it start with (underline) char ? what will be happened ? because i've see a code like that . starting with _ !!

Comment: is there any way to click on tags that they have "id" only ? my span tag have no onclick event and i don't know how can i click on it !! it's working with ajax techniques

Comment: if it start with (underline) char, it works but it's not HTLM standard compliant (so, it could not work one day). What do you mean by "i don't know how can i click on it" ? For select a span without id, you can use with jQuery $('span'). It's select all span tags. You can call the click function on a span without onclick function, but it will do nothing !

Comment: As i said we have the id and it is working with ajax techniques . there's no event and no clickable thing . there is a persian website that using this technique ! Willing you see it ? Thank you

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand. Can you explain exactly what do you want ? Do you want do something when the user click on the span ? Do you want to simulate a click on the span with JavaScript ? Maybe you want to add an onclik event with Javascript and keep the spans with the only "id" attribut ?

Comment: No , see the topic title please :) : *How to click on </span> Tag ? (((((Webbrowser - Delphi)))))* . i say we have a html page . this page have some Tabs that created with span tag . we want to click on Tabs (spans) but they have no onclick event such as submit buttons . but they have id . see this page please : *http://up.iranblog.com/Files7/c0f6ffffdbc94927a9b9.rar* the page have a tabpanel with 4 tabpages . Thank you

Comment: sorry I did not understand the "Webbrowser - Delphi" :). I don't know this technologie, but I have seen this application http://delphi.dev-dz.com/codesource/navigateur.php with source http://delphi.dev-dz.com/codesource/navigateur.zip (sorry it's a frensh ressource but perhaps it's can help you). Why not use a button (or an other clickable element) ?

Answer (score 1):

inside span onclick="yourJsFunctionishere();

Comment: Hello , is there any way to click on tags that they have "id" only ? my span tag have no onclick event and i don't know how can i click on it !!!